# PHP Combining Two Arrays Using array_combine()

Tags: php, arrays

But I receive 2 errors executing the code below:

> Message: Undefined index: rt_default_price
>   Filename:
>   controllers/reservations.php Line Number: 24
>
> Message: Illegal offset type
>   Filename: controllers/reservations.php
>   Line Number: 24

Line number 24 is...

```
$combined[] = array($key => $arrVals[$i]);
```

**Controller (reservations.php)**

```
$arrVals['rt_name'] = $this->reservations_model->pop_room_type(); /* This is the 1st Array:

Array
(
[rt_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [rt_name] => Business
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [rt_name] => Econ
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [rt_name] => Luxury
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [rt_name] => VIP
            )

    )

)
*/

$arrKeys['rt_default_price'] = $this->reservations_model->pop_room_price(); /* This is the 2nd Array:


Array
(
[rt_default_price] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [rt_default_price] => 50000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [rt_default_price] => 25000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [rt_default_price] => 75000
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [rt_default_price] => 100000
            )

    )

)
*/



$combined=array();
foreach ($arrKeys as $i => $key) {
$combined[] = array($key => $arrVals[$i]); // Line 24
}

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($combined);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    )

)
*/

$this->load->view('/main/new_reservation', $combined);
```

**View (main/new_reservation.php)**

```
<?php
echo form_dropdown('room_type', $combined);
?>
```

**Model (reservation_model.php)**

```
function pop_room_type() {
    $this->db->select('rt_name');
    $query=$this->db->get('room_type');
    return $query->result_array();
}

function pop_room_price() {
    $this->db->select('rt_default_price');
    $query=$this->db->get('room_type');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: `$combined[] = array($key => $arrVals[$i]);` show few more lines.

Comment: @som Here's the complete function http://paste.ubuntu.com/5845763

Comment: What do you want ? I think you want to merge to array.

Comment: You're iterating $arrKeys but taking the data from $arrVals. They don't have the same keys which is what is causing those undefined index errors. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Chelsea I originally want to populate a dropdown with the data from a table. But the array returns with the same key for each value (please  see this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5845766) and ultimate causing values of the dropdown to be the same as well (please see this: http://i.imgur.com/7yUHT9V.png).

Comment: @som I'm expecting this array: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5845792/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve but please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
$combined=array('rt_name'=>array());
foreach ($arrKeys['rt_default_price'] as $i => $defaultPrice) {
  $combined['rt_name'][$i]=array(reset($defaultPrice)=>reset($arrVals['rt_name'][$i]));
}
```

Please note that this does depend on the indexes being the same; if that is not always the case, checking should be added to make sure the indexes exist.

The reset function returns the first element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Change this
$arrVals['rt_name'] = $this->reservations_model->pop_room_type(); /* This is the 1st Array:
to
$arrVals = $this->reservations_model->pop_room_type(); /* This is the 1st Array:

Change this
$arrKeys['rt_default_price'] = $this->reservations_model->pop_room_price(); /* This is the 2nd Array:
to
$arrKeys = $this->reservations_model->pop_room_price(); /* This is the 2nd Array:

Comment: >Message: Illegal offset type    
>Filename: controllers/reservations.php    
>Line Number: 26    

Line number 26 is $combined[] = array($key => $arrVals[$i]);